azd cli Unable to connect in linux bash
I installed azd cli for linux bash following the instructions here .
When I run azd auth login in bash , an URL to login.microsoftonline.com opens in the browser asking to pick an account or use another account. When I do either of them I get Unable to connect in the browser. The URL's are like http://localhost:34585/?code=0.AbcAGCze- .... or http://localhost:40607/?code=0.AbcAGCze- ... ( Not pasting the full URL assuming security issues )
